# Why this is the octonions?

Tags: octonions

[image]

The multiplication table is different from [that of the octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Definition) what I know. I tried to find suitable basis change for which the multiplication table coincide with wikipedia, but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the article for [octonion **algebra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion_algebra). In short, the wikipedia link in your question is about the classical octonions, whereas the Humphreys' handles the construction of [split-octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion#Zorn%27s_vector-matrix_algebra) due to [Max August Zorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_August_Zorn).